# regex match unique results

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following situation, I'm searching in a HTML string for the attributes.

I have the following regex which works alright, but I want to get just unique results, of course I can apply some filter to the results array but I think this is achievable with pure regex.

https://regex101.com/r/UqCuJS/1

So in this situation class is returned twice, but I only want 1 time:

`['class', 'data-text']` not `['class', 'data-text', 'class']`

```js
const html = `<div class="foo">
    <span data-text="Some string" class="bar"></span>
</div>`

console.log(html.match(/[\w-:]+(?=\s*=\s*".*?")/g))
```

http://jsbin.com/bekibanisa/edit?js,console

Comment: Can you include full `javascript` tried at Question? Are you using `.split()` or `.match()` to get array of matches?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/bekibanisa/edit?js,console check this out, .match

Comment: See http://jsbin.com/yofozabilu/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your answer seems right, can you post it with an explanation of what is happening?

Comment: Keep in mind that multi grouping (@WiktorStribiżew example) has big performance penalties. So I suggest you to use filter instead

Comment: Yes, the greedy patterns with a construct matching any char, any number of times, will cause much backtracking. Use `/[\w-:]+(?=\s*=\s*"[^"]*")/g` and use `.filter()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass result of `.match()` to `Set`, which does not allow duplicate values. If necessary convert `Set` instance back to `Array`.

```js
const html = `<div class="foo">
 <span data-text="Some string" class="bar"></span>
</div>`
// or use existing `RegExp`
console.log([...new Set(html.match(/([\w-]+)(?=[=]")/g))])
```

Comment: this is awesome

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the '/g' global modifier

```
console.log(html.match(/[\w-:]+(?=\s*=\s*".*?")/))
```

Comment: then dosent match data-text, just first attribute, its not correct!

Comment: It'll only return the first match not the complete one.